# How to redirect with ajax django

Tags: ajax, django

The problem i am facing over here is that i am not able to see the cartempty page when items count is 0.
here is the view

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'remove':
    cart_item.delete()

    if cart_item.cart.items.count() == 0:
        return render(request , "carts/cartempty.html", {})
    else:
        try:
            total = cart_item.line_item_total
        except:
            total = None
        try:
            original_total = cart_item.cart.original_total
        except:
            original_total = None

        try:
            final_total = cart_item.cart.final_total
        except:
            final_total = None

        try:
            total_items = cart_item.cart.items.count()
        except:
            total_items = 0


        data = {
            "line_total": total,
            "original_total": original_total,
            "final_total" :final_total,
            "total_items": total_items
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

How can i redirect to cartempty page using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. Did you try?

```
return render_to_response('carts/cartempty.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

OR

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/carts/cartempty/")
```

instead of:

```
return render(request , "carts/cartempty.html", {})
```

Comment: A double return? The second one will never execute.

Comment: Hahahaha, LOL. Are you serious? I was suggesting one of both. So, I edited my answer. Sorry...